# Terms of service- or can I distribute a copy of a "free" software on my website?

Tags: vmware

I have a copy of VMware player 12.0.1

It either needs a key or my email address to be used.

I want to know if I can upload this file to my website as part of an installation instructions for Ubuntu.

Can I do that? If not please explain why.

Thank you

Comment: What does its license say?

Comment: https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/downloads/eula/universal_eula.pdf  This looks like the aula, does not mention redistribution.

Answer (score 0):

Found on the vmware's website's temrs of use:

Anti-Piracy/License Compliance
VMware protects its technology vigilantly and permits others to use it by virtue of license agreements.  The use or distribution of VMware software without permission from VMware is software piracy.  VMware distributes and sells its product through a channel network of distributors and resellers worldwide.  VMware does not distribute or sell its product through unauthorized channels such as auctions, peer-to-peer networking, or through illegal download sites offering key or serial number generators.  If you are contemplating or have obtained VMware software through one of these avenues, you likely will find yourself with pirated software.  Please contact VMware here for assistance with your own or another’s unauthorized use of VMware software.

https://www.vmware.com/help/legal.html

Copies of the software without permission is not allowed.

EDIT: Virtual Box is licensed under GNU version 2, which permits redistribution as long as I give a copy of the license and where to download virtual box.